# How to resize a complex table with subcaptionboxes?

Tags: tables, subcaption

Let's say I'd like to scale the following table down. It's actually much larger, but this will do as a minimal example. I've seen many solutions using `resizebox`, but that doesn't quite work in this case, as I need not only to scale down the `tabular` environments, but also the sub-captions.

```
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Study 2: Summary of the answers to the demographics questionnaire.}\label{tab:study-2:demographics}

    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{A1: Have you studied music?}{
        \begin{tabular}{@{}rccc}
        \toprule
        & {\bf\small no}
        & {\bf\small informally}
        & {\bf\small formally} \\ \midrule
        {\bf\small beginners}       & {\bf 7} & 5 &       2  \\
        {\bf\small non-beginners}   &      0  & 1 & {\bf  9}  \\
        {\bf\small total}           &      7  & 6 & {\bf 11} \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }\quad
    \subcaptionbox{A2: Do you play a musical instrument?}{
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \toprule
        {\bf\small no}
        & {\bf\small one}
        & {\bf\small more} \\ \midrule
        {\bf 10} & 3 &      1  \\
                0  & 2 & {\bf 8} \\
        {\bf 10} & 5 &      9  \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
```

Can this even be done? Should I just export the table as a PDF and reimport it as a figure?

Comment: Off-topic: `\bf` is a deprecated command since more than 20 years. Replace it with `\bfseries`

Comment: Alright, but you got me excited there for a moment… :)

Comment: Call me `The One That Causes Excitement` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Sure... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling tabular material using something like a `\resizebox` directive is almost invariably a poor solution.

By all means, do determine whether using either `\small` or `\footnotesize` succeeds in typesetting the tabular material without exceeding the width of the text block. However, unless you are openly contemptuous of your readers -- or if you don't care if you're perceived by your readers as being contemptuous of them -- don't try `\scriptsize`, let alone `\tiny`.

As Christian He-Who-Causes-Excitement [!] Hupfer has already pointed out in a comment, `\bf` is badly deprecated. In fact, it's no longer defined in the LaTeX kernel. Some document classes (such as the KOMA-Script classes and `memoir`) will crash if they encounter `\bf`, `\it`, `\tt`, and the like. Instead, use `\bfseries`, `\itshape`, `\ttfamily`, and so on.

Especially if your tabular-like environments contain quite a few columns, reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` (default value: 6pt) quite frequently is all that's needed to make the tabular material fit inside the text block. Suppressing the whitespace padding on the left and right hand edges of the `tabular` material, by inserting `@{}` directives, can also be useful.

If the material in each subcaptionbox is sufficiently voluminous or complex so as to make it impossible to place two (or more) such boxes next to each other, even after having tried `\small` and `\footnotesize` and having reduced the value of `\tabcolsep`, so be it. Start placing the subcaptions one below the other, rather than side by side.

Do study the following, modified, form of your code and determine whether it can serve as a template for your formatting needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,subcaption,ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\caption*{Study 2: Summary of answers to demographics questionnaire.}
\label{tab:study-2:demographics}

\small % or \footnotesize, if necessary
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}  % default value: 6pt

    \subcaptionbox{A1: Have you studied music?}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rccc@{}}
        \toprule
        & \bfseries no & \bfseries informally & \bfseries formally \\
        \midrule
        \bfseries  beginners     & \bfseries 7 & 5 & 2  \\
        \bfseries  non-beginners &  0          & 1 & \bfseries 9  \\
        \bfseries  total         &  7          & 6 & \bfseries 11 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }\hfill  % maximize the distance between the subcaptionboxes
    \subcaptionbox{\Centering A2: Do you play a musical instrument?}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
        \toprule
        \bfseries no & \bfseries one & \bfseries more \\ 
        \midrule
        \bfseries 10 & 3 & 1 \\
        0            & 2 & \bfseries 8 \\
        \bfseries 10 & 5 & 9 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the thorough reply. On using smaller font sizes, I tried that avenue but am I missing something or do I have to repeat `\small` for every cell? I tried using it right at the beginning of the `table` environment, and it didn't quite work (as in, it didn't work at all). Other than that, unfortunately the problem I'm facing is that the tables are long, rather than wide -- picture my example times three. I'm happy to make them "wider" and "shorter" by manipulating the subtables, but that means they become too wide, that's why I thought resizing wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: @Morpheu5 - Note that I've placed a `\small` directive right after `\label`; its scope is the remainder of the current environment (which happens to be the `table` environment). For sure, it's not necessary to issue a `\small` directive for each and every cell. If your tables tend to be long rather than wide, you should explore the `longtable` environment. (As you've no doubt discovered by now, `table` environments cannot span more than 1 page.)

Comment: I feel deeply honored ;-)

Comment: Mmmh, I don't know why placing a `\small` right after `\begin{table}[tb]` didn't work. I moved it to right before the first `subcaptionbox` et voilà. Anyway, as it turns out, none of these help very much in my case, as I can give at most one or two lines back to the main text. The problem is that these tables fit in a page, so no need to use `longtable`, but they do take up most of the page anyway, so you get only a few lines of body text either above or below a giant table. I might consider placing them in a page of their own, but for some reason they always end up at the end of the document.

Comment: @Morpheu5 - It might be worth your time to post a new query, in which you provide some code examples that are closer to tables you are actually trying to typeset. Do be sure to provide some information about the actual size of the text block and the font and main font size in use in your document.

Comment: @Morpheu5 your example shows `[p]` so the table will never have body text on the same page, but then your comment suggests you are using `[tb]` which for large tables is quite likely to force them to the end of the document as it prevents latex placing the table on a float page.

Comment: I spotted that too late, thanks, edited. You are right, I'm using `[htb]`.

Comment: @Morpheu5 - If you're going to mention `h`, `t`, and `b`, you might as well also mention `p`, i.e., write `[htbp]` as the placement specifier.